# sql.rows(select * from book) return a Object[].How can I get every key and value of every Object?

Tags: groovy

I am beginner.sql. I'm using the class `groovy.sql.Sql`, and I have a problem.

```
Sql.rows( 'select * from book' )
```

returns an Object[].

How can I get every key and value of every Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sql.rows` doesn't return `Object[]`, [it returns a](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#rows%28groovy.lang.GString%29) `List<GroovyRowResult>`

So you should be able to do:

```
Sql.rows( 'select * from book' ).each { row -> println row.ID }
```

Or, you could use `eachRow` like:

```
Sql.eachRow( 'select * from book' ) { row -> println row.ID }
```

To print all available fields, you should also be able to do:

```
println Sql.firstRow( 'select * from book' ).keySet()
```

Comment: @ItsYours glad I could help :-)  Have fun!